# How to search a particular word in a text file on Android

Tags: java, android, search

I would like to know of there are any methods/samples where I can search for a particular word in a text file where it consist of a list of words without looping each line to get the word?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the end you will have to search through all lines since you can't tell if your word is on line 4 for example if you only search 3 lines.

Basically you can just read the file in and scan for your word. Lines won't do since a word can start on the previous line and end on the next line.

Comment: meaning there is no way to search for a word without looping each line? coz i am thinking of doing something like each line will have a word like Apple, Banana , Coconut or so ,and then it will search for the word like Coconut directly without the need to loop for each line. is it possible to search of a word directly without the need of sequence algorithm and some algorithm that does that? Ty

Comment: I don't get what are you trying to achieve. How are you going to observe something if you don't look at it?

Comment: I am doing my final year project and I was told not to use any database because it will effect its performance, and instead use the text file as a database to store a list of words in it and to look for a word in a text file without the use of sequencing algorithm. Because I am a little confused , well according to what I know is that I have to search for a word by looping line by line to see if it match and if it doesn't match it will move on to the next line until it had found the matching word and stop. But they told me that this is sequence algortm and not to use this but use another algo

Answer (score 0):

create a string from your text (lots of examples on google) then:

```
    if(myString.contains("this character sequence")){
    //Do Something 
    }
```